# Powershell edit Headers in CSV before export

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory, office365

Hello I am trying to make a small PS Script that Gets the Users from one OU and also some of the Headers and then edits the headers(So that I can import them to Office365) before saving.

```
$Select = @{
'Filter' = '*'
'searchbase'='OU=TESTOU,DC=corp,DC=test,DC=com'
'Properties'= @("GivenName","SurName","DisplayName","samaccountname","Streetaddress","state","City","PostalCode","Country","Title","Company","Department","Office","telePhonenumber")
}

Get-ADUser @select|Select-Object -Property $propertyTranslation|export-csv c:\Test0218.csv -notype

$propertyTranslation = @(
    @{ Name = 'UserPrincipalName'; Expression = { $_.'User Name' } }
    @{ Name = 'GivenName';   Expression = { $_.'First Name'  } }
    @{ Name = 'SurName';   Expression = { $_.'Last Name'  } }
    @{ Name = 'DisplayName';   Expression = { $_.'Display Name'  } }
    @{ Name = 'Title';   Expression = { $_.'Job Title'  } }
    @{ Name = 'Department';   Expression = { $_.'Department'  } }
    @{ Name = 'telePhonenumber';   Expression = { $_.'Office Phone'  } }
    @{ Name = 'StreetAddress';   Expression = { $_.'Address'  } }
    @{ Name = 'City';   Expression = { $_.'City'  } }
    @{ Name = 'PostalCode';   Expression = { $_.'Zip or Postal Code'  } }
    @{ Name = 'Country';   Expression = { $_.'Country or Region'  } }
)

(Import-Csv -Path 'c:\Test0218.csv') |
Select-Object -Property $propertyTranslation |
Export-Csv c:\Test0230.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

This does not work because the contet of the file is crap :(
[image]

As you can see the File Headers stay the same and alos now there is no Information at all (Just 2 Instead of 11) I filled out all the Information and when just exporting the CSV with the AD Headers it has the information needed.
Can someone help me?

BR

Answer (score 0):

I would debug this in the ISE or VSCode and unroll your pipelines to assist with that endeavor.

As a mock up of what you are trying to do, I created the following using some predefined csv data, which I find helpful in debugging any csv-related workflow.

```
$csvdata = @'
"Header One", "Header Two"
foo, bar
baz, boo
'@

$xlate = @(
    @{Name = 'H1'; Expression = {$_.'Header One'} }
    @{Name = 'H2'; Expression = {$_.'Header Two'} }
)

$csv = ConvertFrom-Csv $csvdata

$newcsv = $csv | Select -Property $xlate | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation

"csv----------------------"
$csv

"newcsv----------------------"
$newcsv
```

Gives:

```
csv----------------------
Header One Header Two
---------- ----------
foo        bar       
baz        boo       
newcsv----------------------
"H1","H2"
"foo","bar"
"baz","boo"
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have your property-name translation backwards:

- You're giving the new properties names that the original properties already have (e.g., `GivenName`)
- You're trying to access properties on the input object using names they do *not* have (e.g., `First Name`).

If you want to ***rename* properties of a given input object**, use the following approach:

```
$co = [pscustomobject] @{ one = 1 } # sample input object

$co | Select-Object @{ n = 'eins'; e = 'one' } # rename 'one' to 'eins'
```

That is, assign the new name to the `n` (`Name`) key, and reference the original property name in the `e` (`Expression`) key.

Comment: I have changed it. Now the Headers are correct but I dont get the second row (Information like johnnydoe@test.com, Johnny, Doe, Johnny Doe, Sales Manager, Sales etc...)

Comment: @Stefan.D: You're applying the transformation _twice_, which I assume is not your intent: once after `Get-AdUser` and then again after `Import-Csv`